# Calling for IDs returning undefined

Tags: jquery

I want to create my own contact form validation script using Bootstrap 3.2 + securimage captcha add-on. However, the IDs of my input + textarea elements are being returned as 'undefined' -- rendering my function to show errors useless.

I wonder what I've been missing. I hope someone can point me to the right direction.
I'm using jQuery 1.11 btw.

**Here's my HTML code:**

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <b><label class="toFade">Name</label></b>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="contact-name" class="form-control toFade" placeholder="Name" />
                <span class="input-group-addon toFade"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
            </div>
            <p class="help-block text-danger hidden-elem">Please input name!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <b><label class="toFade">Email Address</label></b>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="contact-email" class="form-control toFade" placeholder="Email Address" />
                <span class="input-group-addon toFade"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
            </div>
            <p class="help-block text-danger hidden-elem">Please input e-mail!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-4 toFade">
            <img id="captcha" src="lib/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 toFade">
            <input type="button" id="btnChangeCaptcha" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Change captcha image" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group margin-custom-xs">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <b><label class="toFade">Making sure you aren't a robot</label></b>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="contact-captcha" class="form-control toFade" placeholder="Captcha code shown above" />
                <span class="input-group-addon toFade"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
            </div>
            <p id="error-captcha" class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <b><label class="toFade">Message</label></b>
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea rows="5" id="contact-message" class="form-control toFade" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <span class="input-group-addon toFade"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
            </div>
            <p class="help-block text-danger hidden-elem">Please input message!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" id="submitFeedback" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg toFade">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**And my jQuery function:**

```
    // contact form submit
    $('#submitFeedback').click(function() 
    {
        var hasErrors = false;

        // clear error messages
        contactForm.clearErrors();

        // can skip buttons because it has values
        $('#contactForm input, textarea').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).val()) {
                alert($(this).id);
                hasErrors = true;
                contactForm.addError($(this));
            }
        });

        if(hasErrors) {
            return false;
        }
    });

var contactForm = {
    clearErrors: function() {
        $('.help-block').hide();
    },
    addError: function($input) {
        $input.siblings('.help-block').show();
    }
};
```

**NOTE:** Omitted `$(function()...` because the source code I pasted here came from my jsFiddle link.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/02t0kx9d/

Thank you and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).id` should be `$(this).attr('id')` or `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

Use this.id or $(this).attr('Id').

Both will work..